# How to create index for join tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to indexing and running into an issue where Postgresql keeps saying there's an error with my code.

Do I need to add the foreign key on the `bookings` table that references the primary key of the `members` table.

How can I implement indexing if my SQL table structure is as follows and I have a JOIN query with WHERE clause using `joindate`

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings b
JOIN members m ON m.memid = b.memid WHERE joindate > '2012-08-01';
```

```
bookings                                   members
---------                                 ----------
PK: bookid                                 PK: memid
facid                                      surname
memid                                      firstname
starttime                                  address
slots                                      joindate
                                           recommendedby
```

My attempted query

```
CREATE JOIN INDEX join_memid_index FOR members JOIN bookings ON  bookings.memid = members.memid
```

This is the error I got when I run above query

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "JOIN"
> LINE 1: CREATE JOIN INDEX join_memid_index FOR members JOIN bookings...
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 8

Comment: Index not needed for joining (it is used for performance increase). *Postgresql keeps saying there's an error with my code* Provide complete and unchanged query text and complete unchanged error message.

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using?

Comment: If you're working with postgresql, why have you tagged the question [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]? Those are different database products

Comment: where did you get 'CREATE JOIN INDEX' -join in an index create is not mentioned in postgresql documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html

Comment: `CREATE INDEX`, not `CREATE JOIN INDEX`.

Comment: I'm using PgAdmin4, and sorry for tagging mysql and sql-server

Comment: CREATE INDEX doesnt allow me to create an index from 2 tables

Comment: @Akina the complete error message is at the end of my post. there's also the query I attempted

Comment: There is no `CREATE JOIN INDEX` in [SQL Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) list.

Answer (score 1):

Index is a structure local to a table. It only improves the query, not performs the action.

You must index each table separately:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_members_memid ON members (memid);
CREATE INDEX idx_bookings_memid ON bookings (memid);
```

The server will use this index for a more efficient join process if it decides that this will improve performance. If it doesn't decide to do this, it will ignore the presence of the index and use a table scan.

By the way, the server may make an erroneous decision...

Maybe the composite index on `members` which includes `joindate` column will be more effective than single index by `memid`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_members_memid_joindate_1 ON members (memid, joindate);
CREATE INDEX idx_members_memid_joindate_1 ON members (joindate, memid);
```

Only execution plan investigation will show what of above 3 indices by `members` (or none) will be used by server. And its decision may change depends on data statistic (rows amount, both total and matched the condition) and parameter value.